# Filebeat is processing all the logs instead of the specified application logs

Tags: elasticsearch, chef-infra, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

I have an app server, where I have configured filebeat(through Chef) to extract the logs and publish it to logstash(a separate ELK server), and subsequently to ES and Kibana.

I have configured filebeat to process logs only from /opt/app_logs/*.log, but it seems it is reading logs from other locations too, because in the /etc/filebeat configuration directory, I have filebeat.full.yml and other yml files generated automatically, and they seem to have all those other file locations, thus due to such a huge amount of logs, logstash service is getting out of memory within minutes with logstash.log. How can I not autogenerate the other yml files?
I tried to remove this file and also tried to comment out all the /var/log paths from the prospectors, but then filebeat itself is not starting.

filebeat.yml file:

```
filebeat:
  prospectors: []
  registry_file: "/var/lib/filebeat/registry"
  config_dir: "/etc/filebeat"
output:
  logstash:
    hosts:
    - elk_host:5044
    index: logstash-filebeat
shipper:
  name: serverA
  tags:
  - A
logging:
  to_files: 'true'
  files:
    path: "/var/log/filebeat"
    name: filebeat_log
    rotateeverybytes: '10485760'
  level: info
prospectors:
- paths:
  - "/opt/app_logs/*.log"
  encoding: plain
  input_type: log
  ignore_older: 24h
```

Comment: What version of Filebeat are you using? Your config is incorrect for all versions, but knowing the version you are targeting can help in getting you the right answer.

Comment: @A J Sorry for replying so late. The version of filebeat is 1.2.3 (amd64)

Answer (score 2):

The main problem with your configuration is that for Filebeat 1.2.3 you have the `prospectors` list defined twice and second one is not in the correct location.

The second problem is that you have defined the `config_dir` as `/etc/filebeat`. `config_dir` is used to specify an additional directory where to look for config files. It should never be set to `/etc/filebeat` because this is where the main config file should be located. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39987501/503798 for usage information.

A third problem is that you have used string types in `to_files` and `rotateeverybytes`. They should be boolean and integer types respectively.

Here's how the config should look for Filebeat 1.x.

```
filebeat:
  registry_file: "/var/lib/filebeat/registry"
  config_dir: "/etc/filebeat/conf.d"
  prospectors:
  - paths:
    - "/opt/app_logs/*.log"
    encoding: plain
    input_type: log
    ignore_older: 24h
output:
  logstash:
    hosts:
    - elk_host:5044
    index: logstash-filebeat
shipper:
  name: serverA
  tags:
  - A
logging:
  to_files: true
  files:
    path: "/var/log/filebeat"
    name: filebeat_log
    rotateeverybytes: 10485760
  level: info
```

I highly recommend that you upgrade to Filebeat 5.x because it has better configuration validation using `filebeat -configtest`.

Comment: Thanks, This helped!